# Convergence of a matrix product

Tags: probability, matrices, convergence-divergence

Let $A=o_{a.s.}(1)$; $A:k\times k$ matrix and $Vu=O_p(1)$; $V:k\times k$; $u: k\times 1$.
Specifically, $Vu$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,I_k)$.

Can we show that $VAu=o_p(1)$ or $\|VAu\|=o_p(1)$?

---

If $V=O(1)$ and $V^{-1}=O(1)$ then we can show that $VAV^{-1}Vu=o_p(1)$. However, $V^{-1}$ can be unbounded...

---

Related question:

Can $Vu=O_p(1)$ and $V=O(1)$ imply $u=O_p(1)$?